# Find $40! \mod 5^{10}?$ Determine the last 10 digits of 40!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I think it has to do with Fermat's little theorem and Wilson's theorem.
I used $ca (\mod cn)=c(a (\mod n))$ to get $40! \mod 5^{10} = 5^9(40!/5^9 \mod 5)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please learn how to use LaTex next time, it will make your posts easier to read. You have the right idea; you need to look for $\frac{40!}{5^9}$ modulo $5$. You have,
\begin{align*}
\frac{40!}{5^9} & = \frac{1}{5^9}\prod_{k = 1}^{40} k\\
& = \frac{1}{5^9}5 \cdot 10 \cdot 15 \cdot 20 \cdot 25 \cdot 30 \cdot 35 \cdot 40\prod_{\underset{5\not\mid k}{k = 1}}^{40} k\\
& = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8\prod_{r = 1}^4\prod_{b = 0}^7 (5b + r)\\
&\ \textrm{ writing $k = 5b + r$ using Eucildean division,}\\
& =_5 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot (2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4)^8\\
& =_5 -(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4)^{10}\\
& =_5 -24^{10}\\
& =_5 -1\\
& =_5 4.
\end{align*}
You deduce that $40! = 4 \cdot 5^9\ [5^{10}]$ and clearly $40! = 0\ [2^{10}]$. Now, notice that $2 \cdot 10^9 = 0\ [2^{10}]$ and $2 \cdot 10^9 = 4 \cdot 5^9\ [5^{10}]$ because $2^{10} = 4\ [5]$ (consequence of Fermat theorem). Hence, by the Chinese remainder theorem, $40! = 2 \cdot 10^9\ [10^{10}]$ so the last $10$ digits are a $2$ followed by $9$ zeros.

Answer (score 0):

$40!$ is a multiple of
$10*20*30*40*(2*5)*(4*15)*(6*25)*(8*35)*(12*25)$, hence a multiple of $10^{10}$.  Thus, $40!=0 \mod 5^{10}$ and the last ten digits of $40!$ are all equal to $0$.

Comment: No, $5$ only appears $9$ times in the factors of $40!$ : $5$, $10$, $15$, $20$, $25$ (counts twice), $30$, $35$, $40$.

Comment: @Cactus: so what about that last digit? It will definitely be even, but what else can we say about it?

Comment: @PGLR: In your answer 25 appear twice, once paired with 6 and then paired with 12. So as it stands argument is not correct, though answer and the general approach is correct.